# Can I run other methods within a method on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, mongoid

I have a collection of methods in a model. Currently all the methods run on an after_create callback. Like so...

```
class DataAggregation
  include Mongoid::Document
   after_create :report_extras, :primary_income, :income_by_name, etc...
end
```

I want to make all the methods run when I run a particular method in the model something like this...

```
def update_report
      :report_extras, :primary_income, :income_by_name, etc...
    end
```

How can I do this or is this wrong and I should set something up as a unique call in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just call those methods in your method

```
after_create :update_report

# some code here

def update_report
  report_extras
  primary_income
  income_by_name
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple enough, I thought I needed the : or ,'s after each method

Comment: Can i separate them by commas to put several on a line?

Comment: Nop, i believe commas will result in a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, I just found that out. LOL Thanks for the answer.